# count arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like this

```
$array = array(Array('b','d'), 
                Array('c','a'),
                Array('b','d'),
                Array('a','d'),
                Array('c'),
                Array('c'),
                Array('a','d','e'),
                Array('d','b')
                 );

$result = array(array('c'),array('a','d'), array('b','d'), array('a,','d','e')) ;
```

here's my code:

```
    foreach ($array as $part) {
        $key = implode(', ', $part);
        if( ! array_key_exists ($key, $result)) {
            $result[$key] = 0;
        }
        $result[$key] = $result[$key] + 1;
    }
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo "$value of {$key}<br/>";   
    }
```

and i got this:
    2 of b, d
    1 of c, a
    1 of a, d
    2 of c
    1 of a, d, e
    1 of d, b

i want result like this:

```
3 of c      
2 of a, d
2 of b, d  
1 of a, d, e
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: ..you have put an answer yourself, so what was your question?

Comment: you have used $result twice and in such a manner that it would create unexpected output, I would suggest two thing, in $result[$key] , use some other array variable, and try using in_array instead of imploding. Hope it helps!

Comment: Why `2 of a, d`? `array('a','d')` occurs only once in `$array`

Comment: hindmost 2 of a,d there's in array('a','d') and array('a','d','e')

Comment: @user3386333 I don't understand what you want. You have to describe your question more clearly

Answer (score -1):

did you try [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) ?

Bye.

Comment: `array_count_values()` just count one values